# How to get the normal definition of week number with Dates

Tags: date, julia

Happy new year!  It's January 1st.  What week is it?  Most people would say that it's the first week of the year.  Not julia, however:

```
using Dates
for i=2000:2015
    println(Date(i), ": first week is ", Dates.week(Date(i)))
end
```

results in

```
2000-01-01: first week is 52
2001-01-01: first week is 1
2002-01-01: first week is 1
2003-01-01: first week is 1
2004-01-01: first week is 1
2005-01-01: first week is 53
2006-01-01: first week is 52
2007-01-01: first week is 1
2008-01-01: first week is 1
2009-01-01: first week is 1
2010-01-01: first week is 53
2011-01-01: first week is 52
2012-01-01: first week is 52
2013-01-01: first week is 1
2014-01-01: first week is 1
2015-01-01: first week is 1
```

Is there an easy way to get the week number of an arbitrary date in any year, counting the first day as always in the first week *and starting a new week each Sunday?*

Edit: Clarify why I can't just use div(Dates.dayofyear(x),7)+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing looks something like this

```
using Dates
function getWWFromDate(date)
    year = Dates.year(date+Dates.Day(6))
    #How many days since the start of the first ww of the year
    startOfFirstWW = Dates.firstdayofweek(Date(year)) - Dates.Day(1)
    #How many days from the current date to that day?
    doy = Dates.days(date-startOfFirstWW)
    ww = floor(doy/7)+1
    return year*100+ww
end

for i=2000:2015
    td = Date(i,1,1)
    println(td, ": Week is ", ourWeekNumber(td) )
end
```

Basically, every time I want the week for a given date I call this function rather than Dates.week

Edit: I also ended up needing the inverse.  The function below takes a year and WW in the form of YYYYWW like 201501 and returns the first day of that week using this definition (in this case 2014-12-28)

```
function getDateFromWW(yearww)
    year = floor(yearww/100)
    ww = yearww%100
    Dates.firstdayofweek(Date(year)) - Dates.Day(1) + Dates.Week(ww-1)
End
```

Answer (score 4):

The Julia `Dates` module follows the most common, standard definition of a "week", the ISO-Week (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering)).

It's typical practice to include algorithms/functions in a core language that would otherwise painful/complex to implement on one's own. In this case, compare the [ISO-Week algorithm](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/31102e9dcd817b543c76fe69c2207f5f90a1cea2/base/dates/accessors.jl#L35) with what you're suggesting:

```
week(dt::Date) = div(Dates.dayofyear(x),7)+1
```

Comment: Interesting, it seems R, for comparison's sake, uses the North American system where a week starts on the first Sunday, otherwise it is "week 0" - e.g. `format(seq.Date(as.Date("2000-01-01"),as.Date("2015-01-01"),by="year"),"%U")`

Comment: That's what I'm trying to get, but plus one -- the first day is always week 1, but the first week can have 1-7 days in it.

Comment: It should be `round(Dates.dayofyear(...))` instead of using `div` because some week numbers will turn out to be incorrect. Try: `Date(2022, 09, 13)`, it should be week 38 and not 37.